# Android studio Facebook - How to get full friends list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get the full friend list of a person, using Android Studio and Facebook SDK 4.4.+. I have looked for tutorials everywhere but they are all out dated. I just need a simple code without installing any new libraries and I need some more explanation with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that sound like you? Well you found the right question!
What you will need to perform the "Friend getting" is the Facebook Graph API. Facebook has a pretty good explanation on how to use their Graph API + you can test it with their Graph Explorer.

But may be you need more help? Well I can give it to you.

First integrate your Facebook SDK properly and add a log in button, so the person can Login.
From here on now comes the Graph API. I recommend you read the Graph API documentation and the list of permissions after you read this answer to understand this amazing tool even better.

Many say that after a certain update a while ago you cannot get a full friends list. Well they are partially correct. Facebook did change how some commands behave, but others are still at your dispolsal. For example the /taggable_friends

The taggable friends will give you an array of names that are all of your friends, who have not made their profile private. For example I have 409 friends, but this function shows them to me only up to the 406 person, because 3 have private accounts.

How to use the taggable_friends?
In the Log in code add this:

```
 GraphRequest requestet =
                new GraphRequest(
                        accessToken,
                        "/me/friends",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                                JSONObject sum;
                                try {
                                    sum = obj.getJSONObject("summary");
                                    c=Integer.valueOf(sum.optString("total_count"));
                                    fff.setText(sum.optString("total_count"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                );
        GraphRequest requestt =
        new GraphRequest(
                accessToken,
                "/me/taggable_friends",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject();
                        JSONArray arr;
                        try {
                            arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                            JSONObject oneByOne = arr.getJSONObject(1);

                            lmaYOLO.setText(Integer.toString(c)+" "+oneByOne.opt("name").toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        );

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name");
        requestet.executeAsync();
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
        requestt.setParameters(parameters);
        requestt.executeAsync();
```

The first graph request that we use is the "requestet" what I do in there is get the number of friends of the logged in user, using the friends node.

In order to access any node you need to use JSONObject objname = previousobject.getJSONObject("name of node") 
with objname, previousobject and name of node being changable according to your needs.

With taggable_friends it is more tricky, as you will get an Array of objects, each of which will contain a name of a friend. So you can see at the code how I get an Array same as the Object. Now at JSONObject oneByOne = arr.getJSONObject(1), the one is changable to any number of your friends list (REMEMBER arrays start from 0, so the first element will be getJSONObject(0)).

Now from here you can create a while loop, which will go from 0 to the number which we got from the /me/friends

You might have noticed that when I setText I use oneByOne.opt("name"). What opt does is GET the value of that node (in our case the name of the friend), unlike the getJSONObject, which opens the node.

Starting this program I will see on my screen appear:

406 - the number of non-private friends
Biggus Dickus - the second friend in my Facebook list (which is certainly not your Real life second friend).

Changin it to give me my first friend (remember you had to put 0),
I will get
407 (oh I accepted a new friend's request)
Martin Luther King

From here on you can do whatever you want with this code! Have Fund

Comment: @Nitesh You made my day

Comment: @Tobi I wonder where that comment went.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from Facebook API Docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends

> This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
>   If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

This was something Facebook API did to us when they enforced v2 upon all apps.

Thanks Facebook.

Comment: If you were to check my answer, you would see the solution. Works :)!

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** get the whole friend list. Only those which are also using your app.

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: You can, check my code

Comment: If you're using Graph API >=v2.0 this is **NOT** working

Comment: i use v 2.4 and it works so...?

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't understand the difference between friends and taggable_friends. Read the docs

Comment: I did, and one can give you their names, but not more than that. Luckily, with few other commands you can get everything about them

Comment: +you can get their images so works a lot better than your standard and outdated that you are so fixed on using

Comment: But I thank you for your valuable critic, as I am sure you have more than two brain cells and you tested my code and you saw a problem that I could not see. I would be really thankful if you pointed where the problem was, instead of just screaming that it would not work, so you can prove to be helpful at least once in your life

Comment: @Tobi i am using that accepted answer but i am getting some errors..i am able to login via fb successfully..but still wondering how to get friendlist..i am using AS..can you help

Comment: @Lakhan As I wrote, you can't get the complete list of friends. This is a fact, whatever the accepted answer may be.

Comment: @Tobi then which friends can i see in list can you tell??

Comment: @Lakhan Quote of my answer: *"Only those which are also using your app."*

Comment: @Tobi and how to get that??i am getting error with this answer